# Remove html linebreaks between <ul> tags

Tags: php, html, regex, html-lists, line-breaks

I have a CMS system that allows people to also use HTML code, but a `nl2br` is provided at the end of the function, which makes this:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

into this:

```
<ul><br/>
<li></li><br/>
</ul>
```

Now I want to remove these `<br/>`'s that exist between `<ul>`  tags.

I already found another question which asks almost the same, but for newlines. I've integrated this inside my CMS but for one client all the content is already filled in so I have to fix this after the `\n`'s are replaced with `<br/>`'s.

The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277133/remove-line-breaks-from-between-html-tags) provides this as a regex to match `\n` within `<ul></ul>`:

```
/(?<=<ul>|<\/li>)\s*?(?=<\/ul>|<li>)/is
```

I'd think something like this:

```
/(?<=<ul>|<\/li>)(<br>|<br\/>|<br \/>)(?=<\/ul>|<li>)/is
```

Would do the trick, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I am very open for DOMDocument solutions, if there's a way to query linebreaks with xpath this would probably fix my problem.

Comment: Use DOM to parse the HTML and then selectively apply nl2br only to the nodeValues of elements you actually want it applied to.

Comment: If the content has been edited in HTML mode, you shouldn't have to perform the `nl2br()` afterwards, right? I mean, people will insert their own `<br />` s, one assumes.

Comment: Hey Gordon, this is a better solution to how to implement it in the backend. However the problem is that the content is already provided, and already filled in the database with `<br/>`'s. I've changed the method I use to replace newlines but this won't fix my frontend issue for this specific client.

Comment: Maybe this: `/(?<=<ul>|<\/li>)(\s*<br>\s*|\s*<br\/>\s*|\s*<br \/>\s*)(?=<\/ul>|<li>)/is`

Comment: That did the trick, if you could post it as an answer I can accept it :) preferably with some explanation what you did, I am a regex noob.

Comment: a br element is nothing special. you can query it with //br or getElementsByTagName('br'). How to remove elements with DOM has been answered multiple times before, so I only link you to some example code: http://codepad.org/dfJbubsk (am too lazy to find one of the many duplicates)

Comment: I feel like a giant idiot for not thinking of `//br`, just because it's so small and without an ending tag doesn't mean it works differently...

Comment: I can figure out how to query br within ul now, but finding the node index and such so you can remove it (why isn't there a simple removeThis method?) is a lot of sidetracking. Your example works but for all br's. I think I'll just go with the regex for now since it works.

Comment: Query `<br>` from within UL nodes (but not within LI nodes themselves, since you may want those): `//ul/br`

Comment: @Dereleased, I know. However if I then access these nodes through `foreach($xpath->query('//ul/br') as $node)`, then how do I remove them?

Comment: @Gordon yes, when using the `getElementsByTagName` method. However I can't figure out how to only find the `br`'s within `ul`'s with this method. And the way you remove nodes there doesn't work with an xpath approach.

Comment: @Kokos: `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);`

Comment: @Kokos: Also, I would break it up, e.g. `$badNodes = $xp->query('//ul/br'); foreach ($badNodes as $badNode) { $badNode->parentNode->removeChild($badNode); }`

Comment: @Gordon 'getElementsByTagName and query both return a DomNodeList. So what is the issue?' The issue is, the `<ul></ul>` part is not the only HTML present. So with your example it would remove every single linebreak instead of the ones between `<ul>`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provided, `<br>` tags are surrounded by some white-space (at least by new line characters), so this needs to be reflected in the corresponding regular expression.

```
/(?<=<ul>|<\/li>)(\s*<br>\s*|\s*<br\/>\s*|\s*<br \/>\s*)(?=<\/ul>|<li>)/is
```

In many cases regular expressions are NOT the best way for parsing HTML (I definitely agree with the comments above/below), but they are always good enough for some particular purposes.

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide some explanation.

Comment: Remember that this will only work as long as there are no attributes, tags are balanced and everything else is generally perfect.  "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."—Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Yea, I'd rather have a DOMDocument solution. But since this is a very specific problem for a very specific client simply because the back-end wasn't prepared, this won't occur again.

Comment: @Kokos sorry, added some explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples on SO that demonstrate why parsing HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea, so I won't include another one here.

Instead, consider using an HTML parser such as [HTMLCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to accomplish this task.

Comment: Can that be used with PHP? It says "It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files" on the page.

Comment: I didn't use the DOMDocument because I couldn't figure out how to query linebreaks with xpath.

Comment: Concerning other packages / parsers, I feel like it is unnecessary to install something new for one relatively simple task.

Comment: Same question for HTMLCleaner: it is written in Java, so how is that usable from PHP (unless you want to use a bridge)? The question is tagged PHP.