# Regex that removes newlines between tags

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

I'm after a pattern that will consistently put everything on one line when selecting between tags. In this case I want everything within the `<ul>` tag to sit on one line. I've tried a few throughout stackoverflow but none so far with success.

```
<ul>
<li>
<span><span><span>Manager</span></span></span>
</li>
<li>
<span><span><span>physical</span></span></span>
</li>
<li>
<span><span><span>transport
</span></span></span>
</li>
<li>
<span>
<span><span>    Australia</span></span></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Expected:

```
 <ul><li><span><span><span>Manager</span></span></span></li><li><span><span><span>physical</span></span></span></li><li><span><span><span>transport</span></span></span></li><li><span><span><span>    Australia</span></span></span></li></ul>
```

Edit: [Remove line breaks from between html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277133/remove-line-breaks-from-between-html-tags) was probably the closest regex pattern I found, it still doesn't do what I need.

Comment: looked into `preg_replace` ?

Comment: horrendous html, just saying ;)

Comment: Yes Isaac, I've tried a few different patterns with no success (using preg_replace of course). I'm aware it's terrible HTML that's the issue with working with WYSIWYG editors :( I don't really want to add another addition like Tidy either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help? It's very, very basic and could be prone to errors.

```
$test = '<ul>
<li>
<span><span><span>Manager</span></span></span>
</li>
<li>
<span><span><span>physical</span></span></span>
</li>
<li>
<span><span><span>transport
</span></span></span>
</li>
<li>
<span>
<span><span>    Australia</span></span></span>
</li>
</ul>';

echo preg_replace('/\n?<(.*?)>\n/', '<$1>', str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $test));
```

Edit: I re-read your question and feel that wasn't exactly what you were after. So, I made this:

```
function strip_tag_nl($tag, $subject) {
    $tag = preg_quote($tag);
    return preg_replace_callback('/(<' . $tag . '(.*?)>)\n?(.*?)(<\/' . $tag . '>)/s', function($matches) {
        $stripped = preg_replace(array('/\n?<(.*?)>\n/'), '<$1>', $matches[3]);
        return $matches[1] . $stripped . $matches[4];
    }, str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $subject));
}

echo strip_tag_nl('li', $test);
```

Pass it the tag you want things between it to have newlines stripped. For example, `strip_tag_nl('ul', $text)` for your original question... if you do `strip_tag_nl('li', $text)`, you'll get this:

```
<ul>
<li><span><span><span>Manager</span></span></span></li>
<li><span><span><span>physical</span></span></span></li>
<li><span><span><span>transport</span></span></span></li>
<li><span><span><span>    Australia</span></span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works nicely, appreciate the response. It does exactly what I was after which was target specific tags and remove linebreaks.

Comment: Hey I really like your function. How could I adapt it to also work with indentation? This removes the line breaks and I also need to remove the indent spaces between tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something but your example does not show anything else than line breaks to remove from your html to give the result you provided. In that case a simple `str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $string)` works and you don't need any regex.

I think the question would need clarification on what exactly you want to remove apart from line breaks.

Comment: It would work but i'd need to do it in a combination with a preg_replace i'd assume so I could target specific tags not the whole content area. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: OK, then maybe you should first access the Dom to select the block you want and then clean it up. There are built in methods in PHP for that, but personnally I don't find them easy to use. I had good experiences lately with the Simple Html DOM libray though http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/